# Storing Android Sensor Data efficiently, phone stops responding after 10 seconds

Tags: python, android, json, csv, kivy

I'm using Python with Kivy to program a sports related app.
I'm reading in accelerometer and orientation data. A rate of more than 10 measurements per second would be ideal.

Since I will produce a long list of data (Measurements would take more than 10 mins) I tried writing it into a json file. For my goal that would be perfectly acceptable. I just want to analyze the data after the measurement

For that I used the kivy storage module - [see here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.storage.html#module-kivy.storage)

My problem is that after a few seconds the app gets really slow on my phone and the readings I put on my screen pretty much stop updating. After a while I can't even press the button to stop the measurement anymore and have to kill the app.

I built a minimal example that reproduces this problem. When you press the button it starts writing a json file line by line with the row (index,1,2,3) 24 times a second. It's not as bad as my app but after less than a minute I can't press the button anymore either.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.store = JsonStore('hello.json')
        self.recording = False
        self.iter = 0

        self.submit = Button(text="Start/Stop recording", font_size=20)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)


    def pressed(self,instance):
        self.recording = not self.recording

        if self.recording:
            Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / 24)
        else:
            pass

    def update(self,dt):
        if self.recording:
            self.store.put(self.iter,col1=1,col2=2,col3=3)
        self.iter +=1

class DataApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    DataApp().run()
```

Is there some way to store the data line by line so my app can be running indefinitely? I would really appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely that the jsonstore is clever enough to update the file in-place (json doesn't make that especially easy), so it's probably reading and writing the whole file every time.

Try just appending to the file. You can easily do this manually by just writing new lines to a text file instead of serialising to json, or maybe something like the csv module has a convenience function for data rows.

Comment: ah I definitely should have tried this, but I read somewhere that csv and json are similar in speed. Except for appending rows I guess. It works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I put this

```
with open('check.csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write(str(self.iter) + ";1.2;-2;3")
    f.write("\n")
```

in, instead of the Jsonstore part. Works great.